# Getting Windows to detect IBM AS400 provider

Tags: odbc, registry, ibm-midrange

I am trying to get a connection to work on my machine to an AS400 database as per [this](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=100917) link.

I have confirmed that there is no firewall blocking the machine I am working on.  I have confirmed that the connection info works on a different machine with a .UDL file.  I have installed the requisite C++ runtime libraries onto the machine and confirmed it has the appropriate .NET framework (it has 4.7.2).  When I try to run the UDL file with the same connection information, I get "Provider cannot be found. Ensure that the provider has been installed properly."  As far as I can tell I did, but it is not detecting that?

Can someone help me understand how to get it set up so that the UDL file will indicate if the connection was successful or not?  I'm not really sure what is at issue at this point.

*edit*: I got lucky on more searching and so on further inspection, I can see that it is not in the registry editor.  Could that be the issue?  How would I add it there properly so that it shows up as a Data Link so that I can configure it correctly?

Comment: I think it is control panel, administrative tools, ODBC data sources. Then you click add a data source and select the IBM access client services ODBC driver.   But I am not sure in that I do not know what a UDL file is.

Comment: .udl is the extension for Microsoft Data Link is basically just a way to test a connection. If you save a blank text document with the udl extension and double click it, it will open up and let you pick the provider, data source, initial catalog, credentials, all that jazz.  When I go to providers, however, the correct provider does not show up.  ODBC Data Sources as per control panel/etc, when I click add, it does not show any IBM services? If I switch over to File DSN, it shows a folder that says IBM, but inside is only iAccessClient (all empty folders) and support files (help, service, etc)

Comment: I apologize if I glazed over what is to you an obvious answer in ODBC Data Source Admin without realizing, I'm fairly outside my knowledge base here.

Comment: research on installing the ODBC driver for access client solutions.  
https://www.ibm.com/support/pages/odbc-driver-ibm-i-access-client-solutions
You need to install the windows application package.

Answer (score 1):

[go here to download and install access client solutions](https://www.ibm.com/support/pages/ibm-i-access-client-solutions)

after installing the base package, navigate in the install folder and find the `Windows_Application` folder. In that folder, double click on `install_acs_64.js`. That will install the ODBC drivers.

run the `ODBC Data Source Adminstrator` app on the windows PC. Click the `Add` button. Select the `IBM i Access ODBC Driver`.  Make sure to click the `Server` tab and set the default schema and library list.

Once the ODBC driver is installed you can test the connection by opening `Excel` and use the `Data` tab to config a connection to the IBM i database.